# Play Framework with PostgreSQL backend: incompatible generated evolution schemas

Tags: playframework, playframework-evolutions

I'm currently working with a few other people on a Play Framework Project. We are currently in the development phase but we also want to provide automatic dev builds on a server. For testing on production machines, we are using the in memory database which works fine. But for the dev builds on the server, we'd like to use PostgreSQL as the DB backend.

Everythings worked fine up to now. The EBeans generated the 1.sql file, with `SET REFERENTIAL_INTEGRITY FALSE;`, which is *not* PostgreSQL compatible. So my question is: How do I automaticly let Play generate both in memory DB and Postgres valid SQL?

I don't need to run both at the same time.  I want to run one database for local development and one for production.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to use both database at the same time? Or do you want to use memory DB for local dev and Postgres for production?

Comment: Not at the same time, no. Locally dev and remote the postgres for production.

Comment: Here someone has a similar question, and someone else recommends using the same db for development as for  production: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15187594/play-framework-h2-db-evolutions-compatible-with-sqlite-mysql

Comment: @KajMagnus: As I said, this isn't an option. I can't say to my team of developers: 'Sup guys, install Postgres locally.' and I can't make the database on my server public for obvious security reasons.

Comment: If it's not appropriate to install Postgres locally, one alternative is to use a Vagrant virtual machine, with Postgres installed. Then the developers only need to type `vagrant up` and have Postgres running locally. (And install Vagrant and e.g. VirtualBox — which I think is reasonable for a developer to have installed) — You didn't actually say that using Postgres in all of dev/test/prod was not an option? You did however say that you would *like* to use both Postgres and the in-mem db.